Integrate & Unit: unable to determine the units of quantities
In a Wolfram Notebook,
I declare a function F1[x]=1/x where x is in "Meters"
F1[X_] = With[{x=Quantity[X,"Meters"]},1/x]

I integrate F1. Everything is Ok.
NIntegrate[F1[r],{r,1,2}]

But with the function F2[x]=1/(1-x)
F2[X_] = With[{x=Quantity[X,"Meters"]},1/(1-x)]

Integrating F2 gives an error.
NIntegrate[F2[r],{r,1,2}]

"NIntegrate
:NIntegrate was unable to determine the units of quantities that appear in the input."
How can I set units for a function of the type 1/(1-x) and integrate it?

What the message is telling you is that the expression $1-2\mathrm{m}$ doesn't make any sense: you cannot subtract meters from a number. You'll have to add the appropriate unit to the $1$ in the denominator as well

Thta's right! Thanks a lot for your help!

Based on @Lukas's comment, I've modified my function to F3 like this:
F3[X_]=Quantity[1/(1-X),"Meters"]

Then, the integration gives a result value with the unit.
NIntegrate[F3[r],{r,2,3}]

Out[11]=-0.693147m

